# optimizing risk limit in stochastic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, stochastic-analysis, constraints

Assume we want to solve stochastic optimization problem with chance constraints:
$$
\underset{x}{\text{min}} \quad f(x) \\ \text{subject to}: P(x \leq b) \geq 1-\epsilon
$$

where $b$ is a random variable $b=N\sim(\overline{b},\sigma)$. Also $\epsilon$ is called risk limit which is a predefined number (e.g.  0.05). Based on $\epsilon$, analytical reformulation or scenario approach has been employed to substitute chance constraints with deterministic constraints.
$$
\underset{x}{\text{min}} \quad f(x) \\ \text{subject to}: x \leq \overline{b} - \sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-\epsilon)
$$

However, how to choose this risk limit is important. the larger $\epsilon$ is, chance of violation would be smaller but cost of operation is higher.

By this consideration, I want to co-optimize the risk and cost as follow:

$$
\underset{x,\epsilon}{\text{min}} \quad f(x)+c\epsilon \\ \text{subject to}: x \leq \overline{b} - \sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-\epsilon)
$$

I wonder how I can implement this as I don't know how to implement $\Phi^{-1}(1-\epsilon)$ as there is no direct function for $\Phi^{-1}$ . Also I wonder if I can solve it by convex optimization methods?

Comment: How can there be no direct function? How can you then solve the initial problem where you have to evaluate its inverse for fixed $\epsilon$

Comment: I am not sure but I think there are some numerical methods for solving the inverse of CDF.

Comment: It is a function, with derivatives which can be computed given the inverse cdf and the pdf, and using it in a model thus leads to a nonlinear program. Nothing different compared to using, say, a trigonometric function. Of course, if you are using a tool where these functions aren't available, your first step then has to be to implement them.